# Is it fine if I Dual Boot Windows 8.1 And Ubuntu. My hard disk space is 500gbonly

Tags: 12.04, server

**Is it fine if I Dual Boot Windows 8.1 And Ubuntu. My hard disk space is 500gbonly. Will the performance of my laptop decrease??**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is fine. No, performance of your laptop will not decrease, unless you will make weird partioning by yourself.

Personally, I prefer to give Windows as much space as possible, since it has a bigger appetite for resources. So, on your place, I would give Ubuntu 30Gb for root partition + 20Gb for home partition, and the rest allocate to Windows. If 20Gb is not enough, you can always mount a Windows partition(s) and keep your files in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.. you need to be careful during the portioning . This link may help you [dual-boot-windows-8-1-and-ubuntu](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)